# "Find Cases" Page Not Found

Tags: civicase

It suddenly appears that my users get a "Page Not Found" when they click on the "Find Cases" link. It works for me as an admin, but I can't figure out what user permission is responsible for this. Any thoughts? I'm on CiviCRM 5.44.0 and Drupal 7.

Drupal errors show:

Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in CRM_Case_Task::getTask() (line 142 of /home/admin/domains/.../public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Case/Task.php).

Warning: require_once(.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in require_once() (line 452 of /home/admin/domains/.../public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be that they need either "access my cases and activities" or "access all cases and activities", but "page not found" isn't what I'd expect - I'd expect "access denied".

The undefined offset suggests one of the dropdown actions is missing, and "5" is "Print" (and Print is also the default when something is missing). Do you have some custom code (e.g. hook_civicrm_searchTasks) or core overrides that may be causing a problem?

Comment: You're right! That's so strange. After enabling "CiviCRM Export Permissions: access print menu" it worked. I wouldn't have think to consider the print menu to be tied to searching cases.

Comment: Ah interesting. So that's a 3rd party extension then - "export permissions".